# Which endpoints can I call from the token I get by invoking Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook office add-in and would like to get the Contacts of the user that is using the add-in. I don't want to use any way of authentication(SSO) and would like to use the context of Outlook.

I have two questions I cannot get the answer to.

Which endpoints can I call from the token I get by invoking `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()`?
And would also want to know are there any ways to get the Contacts(People) of the user that is logged in but without SSO.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use any way of authentication(SSO) and would like to use the context of Outlook.

SSO is required (may be required) to call the Graph API. But it is not necessary, typically the Graph API is called from the backend side part, you can use any authentication mechanisms to call your API.

Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for dealing with contacts in Outlook. You need to use Exchange Web Services (EWS) by using the [mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox#methods) method, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information, or Graph API for getting the job done.